# Create magento extension using localhost

Tags: magento-1.8

I create my first magento extension .In that extension we replace core edit.phtml in checkout module by custom edit.phtml.
It works properly in my localhost.
I have some following question:-

1)can i make extension in localhost that i upload in magento store.

2)I have some little bit info about it may also non approved by magento team.so which precaution should i take during creating extension.

3)magento team should check code during approval process?

4)i used magento version 1.8.1.0.

Please suggest something...
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> 1)can i make extension in localhost that i upload in magento store.

Yes!  A Magento connect extension is, at it's core, an archive of files to be uploaded to a Magento system.

> 2)I have some little bit info about it may also non approved by magento team.so which precaution should i take during creating extension.

Put yourself in the position of a store owner.  Don't do anything you wouldn't want done to your own store

> 3)magento team should check code during approval process?

No one knows what the criteria here is.  You create a Connect achieve using the interface at `System -> Magento Connect -> Package Extension` and then upload the extension to magento.com.

> 4)i used magento version 1.8.1.0.

Yay for you!

Comment: thanks a lot for your sugestion i work in that direction